# Bibliography natbib, doesn't compare number in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, bibliographystyle

I am trying to create a bibliography on Latex and I am using this code:

```
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\begin{document}

.
.
.
example: \cite{firstbib}

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

But the result in the text is correct. I obtain: example: [5]

But in the reference there is not [5] but only the name of the book/article linked to firstbib.

How can I add [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5e5R.png), [2] and so on at the left of the name in references?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the problem you say you're experiencing based on the information you've provlded so far. Please provide more information. Please also state whether you performed a full recompilation cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice* more.

Comment: @Mico I am using TexStudio, I have created a file sample.bib from it, where I have saved the articles.

Comment: Please confirm that you ran a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more. Please also post a screenshot of the problem output.

Comment: @Micro yes i ran a full recompile cycle, and I added a screen shot

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was not caused by anything discernible from the write-up.  Instead, it was caused by an otherwise-undisclosed `\usepqckage{apacite}` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

The output shown in your screenshot is *not* what is produced by default. All I can surmise is that your document also contains the following instructions:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{}
\makeatother
```

To wit, see the output of the following minimal working example (MWE), which also employs `\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sample.bib}
@misc{firstbib, 
  author = "Anne Author", 
  title = "Thoughts", 
  year = 3001
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{} % <-- is this instruction in your document?
\makeatother

\begin{document}
example: \cite{firstbib}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No I haven't it, but I understand why I don't have [1], ecc.. 

At the beginning I had \usepackage{apacite}, if I eliminate it I see the [1] and so on

Thank you anyway

Comment: Glad you figured out the real cause of the problem. The `apacite` and `natbib` packages are definitely not mutually compatible.